# Disable own lockscreen when device on call

Tags: java, android, telephonymanager, phone-call, phone-state-listener

I am making my own LockScreen using  `Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF` and `Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON`. But when i have a call it still works. I referred this code but it did not work.

```
         StateListener phoneStateListener = new StateListener();
        TelephonyManager telephonymanager =  (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        telephonymanager.listen(phoneStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
    }catch(Exception e){ }

}
   class StateListener extends PhoneStateListener{
        @Override
   public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber)     {

              super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
              switch(state){
              case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                    break;
              case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                    System.out.println("call Activity off hook");

        // Finish lock screen activity
                    finish();
                    break;
              case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                    break;
              }
        }
  };
```

Comment: You want it to disable the lockscreen or keep it enabled?

Comment: I want to disable the lockscreen when i have a phone call.

Comment: @mrZ Did you get anywhere with this?